# Process.Start in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, phantomjs, full-trust

I'm trying to integrate my site with PhantomJS for scraping of dynamic content.
I do this via Process.Start and start up PhantomJS together with my scraping script.
This works great on my devmachine.

On my host, I have examined what trustlevel I have and the level is *Unrestricted* , that is higher than Full trust, right?

Still, I get a permission denied on the Process.Start.

Why is this when the trust level is unrestricted?

[Edit]
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() at StrengthTracker.Controllers.AppController.Index()

the code for executing the process is:

```
        string path = Server.MapPath(".");
        path = Directory.GetParent(path).FullName;
        path = path + "\\data";

        Response.Write("path:"  + path);

        string a = "\"" + path + "\\scrape.js" + "\" \"" + url + "\"";
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            Arguments = a,
            FileName = path + "\\phantomjs.exe"
        };

        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = processStartInfo,
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };

        //pipe the output
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => outputBuilder.Append(args.Data);

        try
        {
            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit(20000);
            process.CancelOutputRead();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            return Content(x.ToString());
        }


        return Content(outputBuilder.ToString());
```

[edit again]
The site seems to reside on a network share on my host.
the path looks like this "\foo\bar\bla"

Is that the problem? restrictions starting something on a share?

Comment: Can you provide the code, which you are using before invoking process.start

Answer (score 1):

You can try
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;317012

or else, it might be a folder security issue. The folder in which the files are kept, must have Modify access to Users.  IIS_WPG under which IIS Process run, that user belongs to Users group, this user must have Modify access on the folder.